# Karate 0.9.1 is not generating cucumber.json which is used for cucumber reports

Tags: karate, cucumber-java

When using **Karate 0.6.1** with cucumber. It is generating test result outputs to **cucumber.json** file in the path specified in the code.

It is then used for generating the cucumber reports using Masterthought.

```
@RunWith(Karate.class)

@CucumberOptions(monochrome = true, features = "SampleFeature.feature", 
plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/site/cucumber-pretty", 
"json:target/cucumber-html-reports/cucumber.json" })
```

But when we migrated to **Karate 0.9.1** to read inputs from csv file. Now, it is failing to generate cucumber.json so the reports are failing with FileNotFoundException.

Attached the plugin for masterthought in pom.xml

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>3.15.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                    <!--    optional, per documentation set this to "true" to bypass
                        generation of Cucumber
                        Reports entirely, defaults to false if not specified -->
                        <skip>false</skip>
                        <!-- output
                        directory for the generated report -->
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->
                        <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</inputDirectory>
                        <jsonFiles>
                            <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                            <param>target/cucumber-html-reports/cucumber-json-report.json</param>
                        </jsonFiles>
                        <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-html-reports/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                    <!--    optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->
                        <classificationDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classifications</classificationDirectory>
                        <classificationFiles>
                            supports wildcard or name pattern
                            <param>sample.properties</param>
                            <param>other.properties</param>
                        </classificationFiles>
                        <parallelTesting>false</parallelTesting>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Can anyone suggests what is changed from 0.6.1 to 0.9.1?

And what should i be doing to generate cucumber.json file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Karate 0.9.0 onwards, the only parameters on the annotation supported are `features` and `tags`, nothing else. Karate is [not based on Cucumber any more](https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/444).

The parallel runner, will generate the JSON you are expecting in `target/surefire-reports` by default. Please read this section of the docs carefully: https://github.com/intuit/karate#parallel-execution

So you have to do the following:

- don't use `@RunWith(Karate.class)`
- use `@KarateOptions(features = "SampleFeature.feature")`
- use the [`Runner.parallel()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#parallel-execution)
- don't use the `maven-cucumber-reporting` as a `plugin`, use it as a `dependency` instead, refer this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo#example-report
- write (a few lines of) code to use the JSON generated as described in the above link

EDIT - note that in 1.0 onwards, the Cucumber JSON is not output by default: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66682940/143475