# Features not runned when using Runner.parallel

Tags: karate

Im trying to run my first simple features with Runner.parallel to get cucumber.json report. But what happens no features are found. I need help to configurate Karate so it is running features.

Current output

```
11:35:55.420 [main] INFO com.intuit.karate.Runner - Karate version: 0.9.2
Karate version: 0.9.2
======================================================
elapsed:   0.00 | threads:    5 | thread time: 0.00 
features:     0 | ignored:    0 | efficiency: 0.00
scenarios:    0 | passed:     0 | failed: 0
======================================================
```

Runner

```
@KarateOptions(features = {"karate.feature"})
public class KarateRunner {

    @Test
    public void testParallel() {
        Results results = Runner.parallel(getClass(), 5, "target/surefire-reports");
        assertTrue(results.getErrorMessages(), results.getFailCount() == 0);
    }

}
```

My karate.feature file is in same directory as KarateRunner.java
If i run feature from IDE UI it is working fine.

I tried this answer but not working [Karate 0.9.1 is not generating cucumber.json which is used for cucumber reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54417411/karate-0-9-1-is-not-generating-cucumber-json-which-is-used-for-cucumber-reports)

Do i need use some .js configs or anything else?

Comment: This is working when i specify path like this

`public class KarateRunner {

    @Test
    public void testParallel() {
        List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
        paths.add(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/test/java/tests/");
        Results results =  Runner.parallel(null, paths, 5, "target/surefire-reports");
        assertTrue(results.getErrorMessages(), results.getFailCount() == 0);
    }

}`

Comment: Follow below link : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61973019/karate-not-able-to-generate-cucumber-report-with-karate-0-9-5/63535458#63535458](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61973019/karate-not-able-to-generate-cucumber-report-with-karate-0-9-5/63535458#63535458)

Answer (score 1):

Your `KarateRunner.java` runs all the `.feature` files that exist in sub-directories. Try moving your `.feature` to a subfolder.

Comment: it has no effect if i place it in sub-directory

Comment: Can you submit an archive of your project? Or have you tried to use the quickstart : https://github.com/intuit/karate#quickstart to see if you could make it work?