# Karate - not able to generate cucumber report with karate 0.9.5

Tags: karate

I am having a problem in generating cucumber report with sample karate framework I have made.
I have followed the steps given for (Quick start - given in karate doc) and then added code to generate report but still reports are not generating.

Here is the Git url if anybody wants to see the structure
https://github.com/techj-sam/sampleAPITest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the `@Karate.Test` for the parallel runner which is a mistake. Please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#junit-5-parallel-execution

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code:

```
@Test
void testParallel() {
    Results results = Runner.path("classpath:api/HealthCheck/com").tags("~@ignore").parallel(5);
    generateReport(results.getReportDir());
    assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());
}

public static void generateReport(String karateOutputPath) {
    Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[] { "json" }, true);
    List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList<String>(jsonFiles.size());
    //jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath()));
    for(File file : jsonFiles){
        jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "REST API Automation - Karate");
    ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
    reportBuilder.generateReports();
}
```