# After upgrading karate version to 1.0.0 cucumber reports are not generated

Tags: karate

After upgrading karate version to 1.0.0 cucumber reports are not generated. though no test is failed

Error message:
Mar 17, 2021 4:54:06 PM net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder generateErrorPage
INFO: Unexpected error
net.masterthought.cucumber.ValidationException: None report file was added!
at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportParser.parseJsonFiles(ReportParser.java:61)

Note:
Working fine with 0.9.6 version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per upgrade notes: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

HTML reports (and other artifacts) will be in target/karate-reports (or build/karate-reports for Gradle)
so if your CI was pointing to /surefire-reports, this has to be changed

The Cucumber JSON and JUnit XML files are NOT output by default
use the builder methods on the Runner, there is also outputJunitXml(true)
Results results = Runner.path("classpath:demo")
.outputCucumberJson(true)
.tags("~@ignore").parallel(5);

If you change as per above in your runner - reports will be generated.